# How fetch cell value using iText fetch

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, itext

Here is an Emp.xls Table :-

```
+-------+-------------+---------------+--------+
| EmpId |  Name       | Designation   |  Salary|
+-------+-------------+---------------+--------+
|  1.0  |   Akon Roy  | project led   | 12000.0|
|  2.0  |   Brey Deo  | manager       | 13000.0|
|  3.0  |   Dean      | delivery head | 14000.0|
|  4.0  |   Clark     | team led      |155555.0|
+-------+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

**My problem** is that i want to create a **PDF file** in which the output will be like:-

```
 Hello <name>,
```

here **name** can be any of the name from the Emp.xls record, given by the **user**.
How to do solve this problem using **iText** and **Apache poi**.

My code is:

```
          public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {

            FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("E:\\Emp.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputFile);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //adding row iterator
            Iterator<Row> rowitr = sheet.iterator();
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Test.pdf"));

            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World, iText"));
            //document.add(new Paragraph("Dear "));

            while(rowitr.hasNext()){
                Row row = rowitr.next();

                //adding cell iterator
                Iterator<Cell> cellitr = row.iterator();
                while(cellitr.hasNext()){
                    Cell cell = cellitr.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()){
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    if(cell.getStringCellValue == "Dean")       
               document.add(new Chunk("Dear " cell.getStringCellValue()+ ","));

                    }
                }
            }
            document.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If it is not possible with iText then pleas suggest me any other open source API
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: guys please help me or give me a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? According to what you say, everything is pretty straight forward. Is your problem extracting information from the table? Or is it creating the result PDF? Or something else entirely? BTW, there is nothing like an *iText fetch*...

Comment: i try to get cell value and compare with excel name field  like:switch(cell.getCellType())  caseCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:                if(cell.getStringCellValue() == "Dean")
document.add(new Chunk(cell.getStringCellValue()));

Comment: but no result in pdf displayed

Comment: Have you checked whether that `if` ever is true? Not by looking at the table but by stepping through using a debugger or else logging? Obviously you first should try and find out whether your use of POI fails or your use of iText. Then supply some short, self contained sample code for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: if i will use if then there is no data fetch from excel bt if i ignor if and write rest code all the cell values are fetched. so How to fetch the only one cell whose value is "Dean"...??

Comment: Without some code, we're going to struggle to work out what you've done wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to one of your comments to the original question, you

> try to get cell value and compare with excel name field like:

```
switch(cell.getCellType())
{
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    if (cell.getStringCellValue() == "Dean")
        document.add(new Chunk(cell.getStringCellValue()));
```

I.e. you use `==` for `String` comparison.

This is something which hardly ever works because in Java `==` applied to objects checks whether the **identical** object instance is referenced on both sides. You, on the other hand, only want to check whether the `String` instances on both sides *represent the same sequence of characters.* For this task, you should use the `equals` method:

```
    if ("Dean".equals(cell.getStringCellValue()))
```

(I also switched the operands to prevent `NullPointerExceptions` if `cell.getStringCellValue()` is `null` for some reason.)

In general using `==` only makes sense for primitive data types and for objects which you know to be unique in what they represent, e.g. `enum` objects.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Pdfs i generate are generallylooking quite technical but not beautiful...